# Display coordinates of centroid of map in box using QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, layouts

I am customising a layout map to print it in PDF with QGIS. I have a Box where i would like to automatically display the coordinates of the center of the map if possible.

How can I do it?

[image]

I am guessing I have to edit the following.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the result in DMS, try this expression construction:

```
[%
'B: ' ||
to_dms(y(transform(centroid(map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent')), map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_crs'), 'EPSG:4326')), 'y' , 2, 'aligned')
|| '\n' ||
'L: ' ||
to_dms(x(transform(centroid(map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent')), map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_crs'), 'EPSG:4326')), 'x' , 2, 'aligned')
%]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly and it is exactly what i wanted :)

Answer (score 10):

Get them with:

```
map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent_center')
```

which returns a `<geometry: Point>`. Then extract x and y values as you like, for example:

```
'X-Centroid: ' ||
x(centroid(map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent')))
|| ' - ' ||
'Y-Centroid: ' ||
y(centroid(map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent')))
```

Replace `Map 1` with the name of your map in print layout.

Comment: Correct. You might need to add a `to_dms` to help about coordinates formatting maybe.

Comment: Could you please explain me how to get this approach? I am trying like: 

to_dms (x(centroid(map_get(item_variables('Map 1'),'map_extent')))) 

But it doesnt work. Thanks.